# Custom error message for firebase for react and redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a Login feature using firebase and redux. I try to implement a custom error message when the user input the wrong credentials like so:

```
// Log in
export const signin = (data, onError) => {
  
  console.log(data.email, data.password)
  return async dispatch => {
  
    try {
      const res = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
      .then(async () => {
        if(res.user){
          const user = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(res.user.uid).get();
          if(user.exists) {
            const userData = user.data() as User;
            dispatch({
              type: SET_USER,
              payload: userData
            })
            
          }
          
          return res
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        switch(error.code) {
          case 'auth/user-not-found ':
                error.message = "User not found"
                break;
       }
      })
     
    }
     catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      onError();
      dispatch(setError(err.message));
    }
  }
}
```

However, after I run my application, the application stuck in a loading loop forever. Can someone help me out? Thank you in advance. Cheers

Comment: Avoid using await and .then together as it decreases readability and can cause issues.